# Web Api - Exception not logging

Tags: c#, exception, log4net, asp.net-web-api

I have the following class

```
    public class WebApiExceptionLoggingFilter : ExceptionFilterAttribute
{
    private readonly ILog _logger;

    public WebApiExceptionLoggingFilter(ILog logger)
    {
        this._logger = logger;
    }

    public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        //Logging Exception
        _logger.Error("An unhandled exception was thrown", filterContext.Exception);

        //Changing exception message to something generic.
        var exceptionMessage = "An error occurred and logged during processing of this application.";

        //Throwing a proper message for the client side
        var message = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError)
        {
            Content = new StringContent(exceptionMessage),
            ReasonPhrase = exceptionMessage
        };

        throw new HttpResponseException(message);
    }
}
```

And I am registering it like :

```
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        config.Filters.Add(new WebApiExceptionLoggingFilter(LogManager.GetLogger("Web Api Unhandled Exception Logger")));
    }
```

I have another filter attribute registered for my mvc controllers and it is registered in the FilterConfig.cs file.  When an exception happens in a controller action this is logged via log4net to the windows event viewer.  When an exception happens in a call to a web api controller action the OnException method in the above handler is hit and the call to _logger.log is made, but nothing gets logged to the event viewer.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue in the end.

I had this in my assemblyinfo.cs

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(Watch = true)]
```

And I needed this

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile = "log4net.config",Watch = true)]
```